# error MSB1021: Cannot create an instance of the logger. Could not load file or assembly

Tags: tfs, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I am very much new in TFS framework, and now i am creating build from last 3 days, all steps passes but fail @ Build Solution with error:

> [error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.fails.png

[image]

My versions are:

**TFS version:** Version 15.105.25910.0

**VS version:** Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprice 2017 (15.9.4)

Can anyone from community tell me whats going wrong with my build.

Build Error:

> 2018-12-29T11:48:37.1011337Z ##[section]Starting: Build solution
>   ***.sln 2018-12-29T11:48:43.4372323Z ##[command]"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe"
>   "\localhost\ARM-Drop1\1\s\LetsGo1\LetsGo1.sln" /nologo /nr:false
>   /dl:CentralLogger,"\localhost\ARM-Drop1_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.0.45\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=f568d794-328b-48cf-a753-e603bc019eed|SolutionDir=\localhost\ARM-Drop1\1\s\LetsGo1"ForwardingLogger,"\localhost\ARM-Drop1_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.0.45\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll"
>   /p:VisualStudioVersion="14.0"
>   /p:_MSDeployUserAgent="TFS_29388952-19c1-40f9-b321-9389f9ab526b_build_17_287"
>   2018-12-29T11:48:43.5382020Z MSBUILD : error MSB1021: Cannot create an
>   instance of the logger. Could not load file or assembly
>   'file://\localhost\ARM-Drop1_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.0.45\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   2018-12-29T11:48:43.5392017Z Switch:
>   CentralLogger,\localhost\ARM-Drop1_tasks\VSBuild_71a9a2d3-a98a-4caa-96ab-affca411ecda\1.0.45\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll;RootDetailId=f568d794-328b-48cf-a753-e603bc019eed|SolutionDir=\localhost\ARM-Drop1\1\s\LetsGo1
>   2018-12-29T11:48:43.7011531Z **##[error]Process 'msbuild.exe' exited
>   with code '1'.** 2018-12-29T11:48:43.7871273Z ##[section]Finishing:
>   Build solution **.sln

Comment: Are you using the hosted agent? It seems that MSBuild could not load the assembly from the path "file://\localhost\ARM-Drop1_tasks\". Is this path a network shared path? Have you tried to add this assembly to the project and submit it to the TFS server? BTW, How about the result when you build from Visual Studio?

Comment: thanks for providing feedback.Today I have added the .dll (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger) into my Project's bin folder and added under source Control as well + the path (\localhost\ARM-Drop1\) I have already shared it to Everyone access. after doing all these changes result is same, also please find the below detail Build Log

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I am trying to find the location of the "(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger)" on the hosted agent but can't seem to do so. Do you know the predefined path to the logger in azure devops @LeoLiu-MSFT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this bug, as I had done lot of changes into the solution file and the build definition in order to resolve the issues but no luck, so the quickest way I have in my mind is to delete the build definition plus uninstall the agent and again reconfigure it with appropriate agent capability and create new build definition and its all work as expected and the build definition got succeeded.